# Windows 2003 - How do I review cpu usage at the end of the day?

Tags: windows-server-2003, central-processing-unit

I have a Windows 2003 server that is doing some strange things and I want to be able to look at the end of the day and see what processes were consuming the most cpu and memory.  Is there a way to do this or do I need to sit and watch it?  I'm just a programmer so if this is something simple then understand I'm not one of you.

Answer (score 2):

Microsoft has a tool called [Windows Server 2003 Performance Advisor](http://www.microsoft.com/DOWNLOADS/details.aspx?familyid=09115420-8C9D-46B9-A9A5-9BFFCD237DA2&displaylang=en) built to help you with exactly those types of issues. Otherwise, you could use PerfMon (Windows Performance Monitor) for this...here is a good [blog post](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/2008.08.pulse.aspx?pr=blog) about using Perfmon.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend a monitoring program to do that for you.

There are several solutions available, but I think the easiest to get setup (especially for a one-off solution like this) is MRTG: http://oss.oetiker.ch/mrtg/

The easiest way to get the data would be if you had an SNMP server running on the machines you want to examine. Can you tell us more about what operating system you're running?

Comment: windows server 2003